# How to make GameOver Screen in GML

Tags: gml

Any ideas ? 
i tried to make it -- i kinda did - after you died the "gameover" text appeared
"press R for restart" that worked just fine the text just did not dissapeared !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do that multiple ways, but the base is that you need an object with a low enough depth so that its in front of everything, then draw a big rectangle and some text over it.

You can create a loose object; obj_gameover - that has the following events:

Keyboard press R: Restart game
Draw GUI event: Code:

```
draw_set_color(c_black); //The color of the screen
draw_rectangle(0, 0, display_get_gui_width(), display_get_gui_height(), 0); //Draw a big rectangle over the GUI
draw_set_color(c_white); //The color of the text
draw_set_font(fnt_myfont); //The font you want for the text
draw_set_halign(fa_center); //Align the text in the center of the screen
draw_text(display_get_gui_width()/2, display_get_gui_height()/2,  "Game over!##Press R to restart"); //Draw a text in the center of the GUI. The # sign is a newline in gamemaker.
```